# MonoGame ArgumentNullException in Spritebatch.End()

Tags: c#, monogame

I switched my Project from XNA 4 to MonoGame 2.5.1. The port went somewhat unproblematic but I am stumpled across a problem i can't resolve. For your interest, the code worked on XNA:

When I am drawing a spritebatch with a basicEffect I get an ArgumentNullException on calling the End() method. This is the simplified draw call

```
// polyEffTest is defined somewhere else, not in the draw function
polyEffTest = new PolygonBasicEffect(gd);  

// the simplified draw call
sbTest.Begin(
  SpriteSortMode.BackToFront,
  BlendState.AlphaBlend,
  SamplerState.LinearClamp,
  DepthStencilState.Default,
  GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState,
  polyEffTest,
  Matrix.CreateTranslation(offX, offY, 0f)
);

// draw something [...]

sbTest.End() // <- End-call causes Exception
```

when I replace polyEffTest with NULL in sbTest.Begin I won't get the ArgumentNullException but nothing gets drawed either (obvious). So I guess it has to do something with the BasicEffect

Here is the stacktrace

```
>   at OpenTK.Graphics.ES11.GL.GetError () [0x00000] in <filename
> unknown>:0    at OpenTK.Graphics.ES11.ErrorHelper.ResetErrors ()
> [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
> OpenTK.Graphics.ES11.ErrorHelper..ctor (IGraphicsContext context)
> [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
> OpenTK.Graphics.ES11.GL.Viewport (Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32
> height) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
> Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GLStateManager.Viewport (Rectangle
> viewport) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
> Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.BasicEffect.Apply () [0x00000] in
> <filename unknown>:0    at
> Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteBatch.End () [0x00000] in
> <filename unknown>:0    at RustyMoon.Game1.Draw
> (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime gameTime) [0x001b1] in
> /home/mereddyn/projects/c#/RMoonMono/RMoonMono/Game1.cs:306    at
> Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DoDraw (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime
> gameTime) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
> Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameWindow.OnRenderFrame (System.Object
> sender, OpenTK.FrameEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
> at OpenTK.GameWindow.OnRenderFrame (OpenTK.FrameEventArgs e) [0x00000]
> in <filename unknown>:0    at OpenTK.GameWindow.OnRenderFrameInternal
> (OpenTK.FrameEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
> OpenTK.GameWindow.RaiseRenderFrame (System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
> render_watch, System.Double& next_render, OpenTK.FrameEventArgs
> render_args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
> OpenTK.GameWindow.DispatchUpdateAndRenderFrame (System.Object sender,
> System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
> OpenTK.GameWindow.Run (Double updates_per_second, Double
> frames_per_second) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
> OpenTK.GameWindow.Run (Double updateRate) [0x00000] in <filename
> unknown>:0    at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameWindow.Run (Double
> updateRate) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
> Microsoft.Xna.Framework.LinuxGamePlatform.RunLoop () [0x00000] in
> <filename unknown>:0    at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run
> (GameRunBehavior runBehavior) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
> Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
> at RustyMoon.Program.Main () [0x00010] in
> /home/mereddyn/projects/c#/RMoonMono/RMoonMono/Program.cs:20
```

I am using MonoGame 2.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 with MonoDevelop.
The polyEffTest is defined like that:

```
public class PolygonBasicEffect : BasicEffect
{
    public PolygonBasicEffect(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
        : base(graphicsDevice)
    {
        this.VertexColorEnabled = true;
        this.TextureEnabled = true;
        this.Projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(
            0, graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0, 0, 1
        );
    }

    public PolygonBasicEffect(BasicEffect effect)
        : base(effect)
    {
    }

    public BasicEffect Clone()
    {
        return new PolygonBasicEffect(this);
    }
}
```

Even if I am calling the End call imediatly after the Begin i get the Exception. I even get the exception if I am replacing polyEffTest with a new BasicEffect()

**Update**

I did some testing on a different machine. I downloaded the same Mono Version 2.5.1 and tried it on a Windows 7 System with Visual Studio. It works. I will try it with a different linux machine the end of the day. In addition, I stumpled across something. I guess there is an issue with unsafe code within MonoDevelop on my main system. But I can't tell you anything until tomorrow.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the Monogame source and referencing that instead of the DLLs?

Comment: yes, and even with an empty project with just the three calls, new BasicEffect, Begin, End. As soon as the BasicEffect comes in, crash. I will try it on a dif. machine tomorrow

Comment: Are you able to look at the exception / inner exception and get any useful details?

Comment: the expception is "ArgumentNullException..." with no useful information. The inner exception is null. The only thing I got is the stack trace. But I guess i am on to something. I added the framework source files to an empty project instead of the assembly and debugged it step by step. I guess it has something to do with unsafe code, because I stumpled across something like that that last night. I will look this up when I am back from work.

Comment: Do you really expect an inner exception from `ArgumentNullException`, the exception thrown early when an argument is incorrectly null? Do you know which argument was null where? The stack trace should take you straight to it.

Comment: The stacktrace i provided does not tell me which argument where was null, or I can't find it. Besides that, the same code works on another machine with the same MonoGame Version. I don't espect anything from but it would be nice if the ArgumentNullException would tell me at least which argument was null, something like "ArgumentNullException in Method foo: Object "baz" should not be null"

Comment: Make sure you call base.Initialize() in the overwirting Initialize function.

Comment: Well, the unsafe mode was not the solution. @ClassicThunder i did. Magus i am looking through the stacktrace, but I find nothing. The exception happens inside the OpenTK Assembly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. I updated all Versions and build the Assembly from Source and invoked the DLLs. Now it works as expected.